# Background text bleeds though into dropdown menu on employer page of Stackoverflow careers

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, design, top-bar

Go to the [StackOverflow careers employer page](https://careers.stackoverflow.com/employer) and select the StackExchange dropdown menu at the top left.

The menu is not completely opaque and the word Products from the background bleeds through making the YOUR COMMUNITIES menu text unreadable.

[image: Dropdown with Products bleeding though]

Comment: keep reporting thousands of bugs per day: from my experience, they give tons of rep :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry about that. The problem is the navigation directly underneath the Site Dialog Switcher has a higher `z-index` than the switcher itself, hence why you can see the title "Products" there. I've updated the `z-index` for the top bar globally throughout the Careers website to a number higher than all of our typical `z-index` ranges to help ensure this doesn't happen again in the future.

This has been fixed on production.